# Sorting arraylist of objects based on String property

Tags: sorting, grails, groovy

I am new to groovy syntax.

I have data structure something like this.

```
[
        {"name": "John", "gender": "Male", "id": "1"},
        {"name": "Max", "gender": "Male", "id": "2"},
        {"name": "John", "gender": "Male", "id": "3"},
        {"name": "Sam", "gender": "Male", "id": "4"},
        {"name": "Max", "gender": "Male", "id": "5"},
        {"name": "Sam", "gender": "Male", "id": "6"},
        {"name": "Sam", "gender": "Male", "id": "7"},
        {"name": " ", "gender": "Male", "id": "8"},
        {"name": "John", "gender": "Male", "id": "9"},
        {"name": " ", "gender": "Male", "id": "10"},
    ]
```

I am trying to sort on it based on `name` property. I need all the records with `name=max` should come first followed by `name=Sam` and then `name=John` and the remaining records that have an empty `name` field or any other value.

Can someone suggest to me how I can achieve this?

Thanks.

Comment: Please add the code you have tried and how it failed (e.g. errors,
stacktraces, logs, ...) so we can improve on it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like

```
def weights = [ "Max", "Sam", "John", '', ]

def sorted = [
        ["name": "John", "gender": "Male", "id": "1"],
        ["name": "Max", "gender": "Male", "id": "2"],
        ["name": "John", "gender": "Male", "id": "3"],
        ["name": "Sam", "gender": "Male", "id": "4"],
        ["name": "Max", "gender": "Male", "id": "5"],
        ["name": "Sam", "gender": "Male", "id": "6"],
        ["name": "Sam", "gender": "Male", "id": "7"],
        ["name": " ", "gender": "Male", "id": "8"],
        ["name": "John", "gender": "Male", "id": "9"],
        ["name": " ", "gender": "Male", "id": "10"],
    ].sort{ weights.indexOf it.name.trim() }

println sorted.join( '\n' )
```

prints

```
[name:Max, gender:Male, id:2]
[name:Max, gender:Male, id:5]
[name:Sam, gender:Male, id:4]
[name:Sam, gender:Male, id:6]
[name:Sam, gender:Male, id:7]
[name:John, gender:Male, id:1]
[name:John, gender:Male, id:3]
[name:John, gender:Male, id:9]
[name: , gender:Male, id:8]
[name: , gender:Male, id:10]
```